# Retrieve value from json based on key provided using cypress

Tags: cypress

```js
let expectedKey = 'Student';

cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/applicationDetails.json').then((appDetails) => { 
    if(expectedKey === 'Student'){
        cy.get('app-screen').find('#code-details').should('have.text', appDetails.studentCode);
    }
    if(expectedDKey === 'Department'){
        cy.get('app-screen').find('#code-details').should('have.text', appDetails.departmentCode);
    }
    if(expectedKey === 'Paper'){
        cy.get('app-screen').find('#code-details').should('have.text', appDetails.paperCode);
    }
    if(expectedKey === 'Results'){
        cy.get('app-screen').find('#code-details').should('have.text', appDetails.resultsCode);
    }
}
```

I don't want to use these many if blocks as there will more keys in the future. Instead, I have to pick the required value for studentCode, departmentCode, paperCode, or resultsCode from JSON based on expectedKey. Any help please?

Comment: Add the JSON file to your question. And from where are you getting the expectedKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access object properties by dot notation (`foo.bar`) or bracket notation (`foo['bar']`). In your case, you'll have to ensure `expectedKey` matches a valid key in your object with assertion before the cy commands.

```js
let expectedKey = 'studentCode';
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/applicationDetails.json').then((appDetails) => { 
  expect(appDetails, 'valid key').to.have.property(expectedKey)
  cy.get('app-screen').find('#code-details').should('have.text', appDetails[expectedKey]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the `expectedKey` inside the `cy.readFile()`, you can do like this:

1. Create a custom command at `cypress/support/commands.js`:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('codeDetailsText', (expectedKey, appDetails) => {
  expectedKeyCode = expectedKey.toLowerCase() + 'Code'
  cy.get('app-screen')
    .find('#code-details')
    .should('have.text', appDetails[expectedKeyCode])
})
```

2. In your test just write:

```js
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/applicationDetails.json').then((appDetails) => {
  //Assuming expectedKey value is available here
  cy.codeDetailsText(expectedKey, appDetails)
})
```